# SQL Stored Procedure did not insert result

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have created below stored procedure under a package (retrieve_user) in the SQL database to retrieve information from another table to insert it into the global temp table (global_temp_tableB).

```
procedure Load_BTable (NumID IN NUMBER) AS

begin

insert into global_temp_tableB (name, age, address, country, year)
select name, age, address, country, year
from table(prepare_tableB.find_User(NumID));

commit;

end Load_LFTable;
```

But when I tried to test and call the procedure from a SQL window using:

```
begin

  retrieve_user.Load_BTable(numid => 739);

end;
```

the global_temp_tableB is still empty but when I use the actual INSERT statement instead of calling stored procedure:

```
begin

  insert into global_temp_tableB (name, age, address, country, year)
select name, age, address, country, year
from table(prepare_tableB.find_User(739));

end;
```

it can return me with the result desired. So I believe that the INSERT statement in the stored procedure is working.

But why it is that when I call the stored procedure, it does not return me with the desired result?

Thank you very much for all your time and attention.

Comment: Please check if any trigger is firing when you are trying to insert

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Load_BTable',N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE Load_BTable
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Load_BTable
(
    @NumID      INT
)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON          

insert into global_temp_tableB (name, age, address, country, year)
select name, age, address, country, year
from prepare_tableB WHERE NumId=>@NumID

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

and try this

```
exec Load_BTable 739
```